# Assign BitmapEffectProperty to Trigger in Code

Tags: wpf, listbox, bitmapeffect

I am creating several `ListBox`-es in code and I am setting the style and triggers in code behind (I have to because each is `ListBox` is different and multiple properties change during the life of the `ListBox`, so there is no way I can do it in XAML).

I do it this way and everything works except adding shadow effect to `IsMouseOver` trigger property.

```
DropShadowBitmapEffect myDropShadowEffect = new DropShadowBitmapEffect();
myShadowColor.ScA = 1; 
myShadowColor.ScB = 0;
myShadowColor.ScG = 0;
myShadowColor.ScR = 0;
myDropShadowEffect.Color = myShadowColor;
...

Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
trigger.Property = UIElement.IsMouseOverProperty;
trigger.Value = true;
trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = ListBoxItem.BitmapEffectProperty, Value = myDropShadowEffect });

for (int i = 0; i < myListBox; i++)
{
  var x = new Style();
  //Bunch of Style setters  
  x.Triggers.Add(trigger);

  myListBox[i].ItemContainerStyle = x;
}
```

Can you help me understand what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Now it works! I have no idea what was wrong before. I am keeping it here if someone needs it.

Comment: BitmapEffect is deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the line

```
trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = ListBoxItem.BitmapEffectProperty, Value = myDropShadowEffect });
```